# How to ask for permission when click on activity link

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-opengraph

In my website, when user is reading an article, if the user are authenticated user. An "reads" action will publish into the user's timeline.

However, when other user click on the link that publisher by above user, it did not ask for permission and go to the link's destination.

How to force ask for permission when click on the link? If accept permission, user will redirect to the destination, If decline, user will remain in Facebook.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript for confirmation, if user click yes then redirect the user to article ex:

in your aspx page for link to call javascript write:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="xyz" runat="server" OnClientClick="return checkUser()" OnClick="xyz_Click" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chackUser(){
if (confirm("Are You Sure") == true) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
</script>
```

In Code behind page:

```
protected void xyz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Resonse.Redirect("your link");
}
```

Comment: I think he’s talking about links on Facebook platform itself.

Comment: I think he is linking Facebook to his own web-site and retrieving data from FB then showing it on his web site, if so he will be having records of links and also he can force permission from his end only

Comment: Yes. I mean the permission should ask when a user click on a link that post in FB before go to my website.